# How do you remove delimiters of a cell/column in EPPLUS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

I am working with a dataset that has a "tab" delimiter at the end of the cells. This ruins my conversion of the cells to become a date format.

I know you can remove the delimiters manually by going to Data -> Text to Columns and then unchecking all delimiters, but how would I do this programmatically using EPPLUS?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that Excel saw these values as strings and not as DateTime.

I had to convert the cells into a DateTime value so that the formatting can apply correctly:

```
for (int row1 = rowDetailStart + 1; row1 <= rowDetailEnd; row1++){
            invoiceDetailSheet.Cells[row1, 16, row1, 16].Style.Numberformat.Format = "m/d/yyyy";
            invoiceDetailSheet.Cells[row1, 16, row1, 16].Value = DateTime.Parse(invoiceDetailSheet.Cells[row1, 16, row1, 16].Text);
    }
```